# Could you recommend a website for uploading files for others to download?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a 500 MB epub file and would like to include it in a post asking about some problem of processing it. I can't use Google Drive, Microsoft One Drive, Dropbox, Archive.org, and more, so I would like to find a website that is shown to work via website-monitoring websites such as https://www.websitepulse.com/tools/china-firewall-test.

Is there a website which allows me to upload the file, so that others can download it to find a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does this feel like a superuser.com post... haha

Answer (score 3):

[WeTransfer.com](https://wetransfer.com/) passes the "Great Firewall of China" test.

When you go to the main site, clicking the 3 dots in the lower-left corner allows you to get a transfer link instead of sending the file with email.

[image]

Please note that files expire after 1 week, so you'll have to re-upload the file every week (which shouldn't really be a problem).